# Different levels of consciousness

Tags: consciousness

The answer provided by @user287279 to  [When does a human baby develop a consciousness?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/24110) is a great answer in my mind which scrapes the surface of what consciousness consists of.

When you look at consciousness and how there are different levels to it, I couldn't initially think of any lower level of consciousness other than described in the answer:

> the ability to sense the world around you in an independent way

But there is the [preconscious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preconscious), where information is available for cognitive processing, but lies outside conscious awareness.

[Dehaene, et al. (2006)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Claire_Sergent/publication/7177242_Conscious_preconscious_and_subliminal_processing_A_testable_taxonomy/links/5a09ad5a458515afc7b0e2b3/Conscious-preconscious-and-subliminal-processing-A-testable-taxonomy.pdf) provides a good rundown on the difference between conscious, preconscious and subliminal processing, along with possible reasons why some knowledge remains permanently inaccessible; however, it doesn't indicate when preconscious processing begins.

I wonder if there is any scientific argument where it is considered that preconsciousness could have started earlier than consciousness?

### References

Dehaene, S., Changeux, J. P., Naccache, L., Sackur, J., & Sergent, C. (2006). Conscious, preconscious, and subliminal processing: a testable taxonomy. *Trends in cognitive sciences, 10*(5), 204-211. doi: [10.1016/j.tics.2006.03.007](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tics.2006.03.007)
Free PDF available at: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Claire_Sergent/publication/7177242_Conscious_preconscious_and_subliminal_processing_A_testable_taxonomy/links/5a09ad5a458515afc7b0e2b3/Conscious-preconscious-and-subliminal-processing-A-testable-taxonomy.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Preconciousness is associated with intense activation, yet confined to sensori-motor processors ; 
 Occipito-temporal loops and local synchrony ; 
 Priming at multiple levels ; 
 No reportability while attention is occupied elsewhere ;

quora could also provide some answers : https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-core-of-human-consciousness/answer/Daisi-Lui ;

preconsciousness could have started earlier than consciousness ;

Freud, S., Strachey, J., In Freud, A., In Rothgeb, C. L., Richards, A., & Scientific Literature Corporation. (1953). The standard edition of the complete psychological works of Sigmund Freud.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. *"preconsciousness could have started earlier than consciousness"*. Are you able to provide anything more definite?